# Accounts in Paypal sandbox show as processing for days

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I upgraded from a personal to a business account. Then went to developer.paypal and it shows two sandbox accounts, but their status is "processing" and has been for days. I need to get testing! Anyone have any idea how long this takes or some ideas of what I may have set up incorrectly to cause this? I tried emailing tech support - no response. I tried signing in with the sandbox account, but it won't accept my login. Help!